# Entity framework inserting to 3 tables the right way and rollback if exception

Tags: .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, rollback, sql-insert

I have a very simple question and I am bangging my head on how to do it EXACTLY right.
**USING ENTITY FRAMEWORK AND ALSO TRYING REPOSITORY PATTERN NOW**
I have 3 tables:

```
Story id PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
Album id PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
Photo id PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
```

I want to INSERT  a new story like this:

```
 _db.Repository.Insert(oneStory);
      Save(); // Save will save it to table story
       oneStory.id; // return id of last added row.
```

Then using id of recently added story I want to save album like this

```
oneAlbum.fk_storyid=oneStory.id
    _db.Repository.Insert(oneAlbum);
          Save(); // Save will save it to table album
            oneAlbum.id; // return id of last added row.
```

Then using id of recently added album I want to save photo like this

```
onePhoto.fk_albumid=oneAlbum.id
    _db.Repository.Insert(onePhoto);
          Save(); // Save will save it to table photo
            onePhoto.id; // return id of last added row.
```

Here is the problem

- What if on saving a Album or photo exception occurs , the story is already added, maybe the album is added too, how to rollback and delete that story or changes?
- -Big question can we get id of recently added row without Save() and by just using insert?
  This way I can do all the inserts and also keep getting id and then save in the end like UNIT OF WORK.

So can some one guide me here how its done PERFECT which will save time and less code and also good structure.
Thankyou.

Comment: Add UnitOfWork pattern

Comment: Add where? I looked into it too. It seems it doesn't have the solution either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Entity framework the `DbContext` itself is both a *repository* and a *unit of work*.

If you want to build additional repositories on top of that, you should inject the `DbContext` into them so that all operations use the same `DbContext` and you only call `SaveChanges` once.

In that case you should use navigation properties to link the objects to eachother instead of the foreign key - since you don't have any key values yet. EF will automatically insert things in the right order and assign values to the foreign keys.

If that's not an option, you can use a `TransactionScope` to wrap everything in one transaction:

```
using(var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
  _db.Repository.Insert(oneStory);
  Save(); // Save will save it to table story
  oneStory.id; // return id of last added row.

  _db.Repository.Insert(oneStory);
  Save(); // Save will save it to table story
  oneStory.id; // return id of last added row.

  onePhoto.fk_albumid=oneAlbum.id
  _db.Repository.Insert(onePhoto);
  Save(); // Save will save it to table photo
  onePhoto.id; // return id of last added row.

  tx.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Hi Andres, so if an exception occurs please tell me that how will I remove those rows which got inserted before ? I mean .dispose() i tried but it never removes them

Comment: That's why I wrapped everything in a `TransactionScope` it is to make sure that all of it is saved or everything rolled back.

Comment: Okay got your point gonna try it now. Just tell me if i call tx.Dispose() or _db.Dispose() before tx.complete() what will happen?do tell

Comment: `_db.Dispose()` is fine - the connection will be kept open anyways until the transaction completes. `tx.Dispose()` before `tx.Complete()` will cause the transaction to roll back and all changes to be reverted.

Comment: Thanks will approve your answer just let me try the method